# Child user can't select view of parent in teradata

Tags: sql, select, parent-child, teradata

In Teradata SQLAssistant, I have created a db user USER1 which has 17 views. This user can do a SELECT on any view, thanks to a profile/role I granted and then associated to him. 
His child USER2 is a db user with the same profile/role as USER1, but my problem is he can't select any of the views of USER1 :

> Table/View **** not found, or you have no access rights

When I check in Teradata Administrator, USER2 has the same right (READ) on the datawarehouse tables used by the 17 views as USER1....

Can anyone help me ?
I can provide more details.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT1 : I have the possibility to do that select, but i need to do a
 `Grant SELECT on table_used_by_view to USER1 WITH GRANT OPTION;` on each table... 
 I really need to stick with the ROLE/PROFILE method, so I can't accept this solution (as you can't do a WITH GRANT OPTION on a role).

Comment: select * from user1.viewname?

Comment: I just  tried and it sends me the following error message : "SELECT Failed 3523 : An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION access to (name of the table used in the view)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of the view, `USER1` in this case, must have `SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION` explicitly granted on either the databases or the tables defined in the view.

`GRANT SELECT ON {db1}.{table1|view1} TO USER1 WITH GRANT OPTION;`

At a high level, this allows `USER2` to access data in another database object without having explicit permissions to access that data granted to `USER2`.

Comment: So it's basically impossible to give the permission to USER2 thanks to a ROLE ? granting select explicitly with option would be the only way to give the select right to a child user ?

Comment: You need to both. First `User1` needs `SELECT WITH GRANT`. Then `User2` needs `SELECT` via role or explicit grant on the view owned by `User1`.

Answer (score 0):

Granting select with option on datawarehouse tables (used by USER1's views) to USER1 and granting SELECT on USER1 to USER2 through a ROLE worked.

Now i only need to give that role to USER1's children when I create them and they can perform a SELECT on USER1's views